# How to make a input component for email input which automatically shows @domain.com

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to build an input component in React wherein user can enter his/her email. However, only emails with @ampf.com should be accepted.

I need to show the text @ampf.com in grayish color as soon as user types in @ symbol in the input box. 
The content entered by the user should however always remain in black color. Only the prediction for '@ampf.com' should display in gray. 
So, if user keys in 'his_email@a', then only 'mpf.com' should remain in gray color. 
Likewise, if user keys in 'his_email@am' then only 'pf.com' should remain in gray. 
And if user keys in 'his_email@something_other_than_ampf.com' then all the predicted grayish text should be removed.
I need to implement this using javascript and css only.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Some examples of the expected behavior:
AnilYadav@ampf.com
AnilYadav@ampf.com
AnilYadav@ampf.com
AnilYadav@ampf.com
AnilYadav@ab''

Somehow these examples are not showing the difference between black and grayish part of the email.

Comment: You can't change styling for a portion of `<input type='text' />` values... So you'll have to fake it by stacking multiple elements. Care to share what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would literally be an input field for the username and then just show a text label inline with the @ampf.com

Then when submitted, simply make up the full email address by combining the username and the static domain string.

```html
<input placeholder=“username” />@ampf.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there are plenty approaches. I just created an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-57733337-yuc0e?fontsize=14) that might help you find your way around.

Feel free to modify and improve it, as it's definitely not perfect.